# The Konjunktiv II as a replacement with regular verbs

Tags: verb

The *Konjunktiv I* is being created by using the stem of the present tense (adding *e*), while the Konjunktiv II is being created using the stem of the past tense (adding *t*).

In the course of that, that is my understanding, are all *Konjunktiv I* forms replaced by *Konjunktiv II* forms, if they are similar to the *Präteritum* forms. In that case, the *Konjunktiv II* forms are being used as *Konjunktiv I* and the Ersatzform *"würde"* is being used to create *Konjunktiv II* forms.

My question is this: The 1<sup>st</sup> person singular ("I" = "ich"), 1<sup>st</sup> person plural ("we" = "wir"), 3<sup>rd</sup> person plural ("they" = "sie") always seem to require the Ersatzform when it comes to regular verbs. Is that a rule?

*spielen (reg. Verb)*

**Present tense:**

> Ich spiele
> Du spielst
> Er/sie/es spielt
> Wir spielen
> Ihr spielt
> Sie spielen

**Past tense:**

> Ich spielte
> Du spieltest
> Er/sie/es spielte
> Wir spielten
> Ihr spieltet
> Sie spielten

**Konjunktiv I:**

> Ich *spiele
> Du spielest
> Er/sie/es spiele
> Wir *spielen
> Ihr spielet
> Sie *spielen

Comment: It is not correct, that Konjunktiv I forms are formed by adding a _t_. For example, 2. Person Singular Präsens Konjunktiv I of _spielen_ is _du spielest_, 3. Person is _er/sie/es spiele_. Please update your answer so we can understand whether your question is based on this false premise or whether your question persists after this. And of course: Hello and Welcome to German.SE!

Comment: Apologies. They are created by adding „e“, I have changed it and changed my question. There was still something that threw me off. :) Thanks and thanks for the welcome.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for clarifying the question.

Comment: German tenses are so different from English tenses, that you can't use the term *past tense* when talking about German grammar. You have to use terms like *Präteritum* or *Perfekt.* In this case *Präteritum* is correct. I corrected this and also made some layout improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give you all these examples just for 1<sup>st</sup> person singular (»ich«). It is very similar for the other constellations.

- **Indikativ**

  > Ich **bin** Österreicher.
  > Ich **will** fort.
  > Ich **darf** zu dir.
  > Ich **muss** heim.
  > Ich **spiele** Klavier.
  > Ich **trinke** Wasser.
- **Konjunktiv I** (indirect speech)
  Don't use *Ersatzform* if Indikativ ≠ Konjunktiv I

  > Man sagt, ich **sei** Österreicher.
  > Man sagt, ich **wolle** fort.
  > Man sagt, ich **dürfe** zu dir.
  > Man sagt, ich **müsse** heim.

  You optionally can use the *Ersatzform* (Konjunktiv II) if Indikativ = Konjunktiv I, but you still can use Konjunktiv I (you don't have to use *Ersatzform,* it's just an option).

  > Man sagt, ich **spiele** Klavier. ↔︎ Man sagt, ich **spielte** Klavier.
  > Man sagt, ich **trinke** Wasser. ↔︎ Man sagt, ich **tränke** Wasser.
- **Konjunktiv II** (unrealistic wishes, unrealistic options etc.)
  When you talk about unrealistic things (wishes, options, ...), you can't use Konjunktiv I.

  > Ich **wäre** gerne Österreicher, aber ich bin es nicht.
  > An deiner Stelle **wollte** ich auch fort, aber ich bin nicht du.
  > Wenn ich Karl wäre, **dürfte** ich zu dir, aber ich bin nicht Karl.
  > Wenn Ilse zuhause wäre, **müsste** ich jetzt heim, aber sie ist noch im Büro.
  > Ich **spielte** gerne Klavier, aber hier ist keines.
  > Ich **tränke** gerne Wasser, aber hier gibt es keines.
- **Konjunktiv III** (this is not an official term) (aka **»würde-Konjunktiv«,** another unofficial term)
  This form has it's origin in colloquial speech, but is so widespread, that you already find it in literature, and according to my personal subjective assessment for "normal" verbs (not *sein* and not a modal verb) it even is more frequently used than the two "official" subjunctive forms.

  - Indirect speech in "Konjunktiv III"
    rarely used (better use Konjunktiv I):

    > Man sagt, ich **würde** Österreicher **sein**.

    frequently used:

    > Man sagt, ich **würde** fort **wollen**.
    > Man sagt, ich **würde** zu dir **dürfen**.
    > Man sagt, ich **würde** heim **müssen**.

    very frequently used:

    > Man sagt, ich **würde** Klavier **spielen**.
    > Man sagt, ich **würde** Wasser **trinken**.
  - unrealistic wish, unrealistic option etc. in "Konjunktiv III"
    rarely used (better use Konjunktiv I):

    > Ich **würde** gerne Österreicher **sein**, aber ich bin es nicht.

    frequently used:

    > An deiner Stelle **würde** ich auch fort **wollen**, aber ich bin nicht du.
    > Wenn ich Karl wäre, **würde** ich zu dir **dürfen**, aber ich bin nicht Karl.
    > Wenn Ilse zuhause wäre, **würde** ich jetzt heim **müssen**, aber sie ist noch im Büro.

    very frequently used:

    > Ich **würde** gerne Klavier **spielen**, aber hier ist keines.
    > Ich **würde** gerne Wasser **trinken**, aber hier gibt es keines.

---

So, here are the rules (rules of thumb, these are no hard rules):

- If the verb is ***»sein«*** (*to be*)
  Do not use the *Ersatzform,* do not use *"würde-Konjunktiv"*

  - Use *Konjunktiv I* for indirect speech if the verb is *»sein«*

    > Man sagt, ich **sei** Österreicher.
  - Use *Konjunktiv II* unrealistic wishes, options etc. if the verb is *»sein«*

    > Ich **wäre** gerne Österreicher, aber ich bin es nicht.
- if the verb is a modal verb (*müssen, dürfen, können, wollen, sollen, mögen*)

  - indirect speech

    If you want to write in German, better don't use *Ersatzform* or *"würde-Konjunktiv"* for indirect speech. Also avoid these form when you want to use high quality Standard German in spoken language.

    - Use *Konjunktiv I* for **formal** indirect speech if the verb is a modal verb

      > Man sagt, ich **wolle** fort.

    In a less formal environment, like having smalltalk with friends, using *Konjunktiv I* is the linguistic equivalent of being overdressed. In this case better use *"würde-Konjunktiv".*

    - Use *"würde-Konjunktiv"* for **informal** indirect speech if the verb is a modal verb

      > Man sagt, ich **würde** fort **wollen**.
  - unrealistic wishes, options etc.
    In case of unrealistic wishes, options etc. "würde-Konjunktiv" is the best choice also for modal verbs, even in formal settings and for written German.

    - Use *"würde-Konjunktiv"* for unrealistic wishes, options etc.  if the verb is a modal verb

      > An deiner Stelle **würde** ich auch fort **wollen,** aber ich bin nicht du.
- for all other verbs

  - indirect speech

    If you want to write in German, better use the *Ersatzform* (Konjunktiv II). Also *"würde-Konjunktiv"* is allowed. This applies also for high quality spoken Standard German. For informal speech you should prefer *"würde-Konjunktiv".*

    - Use *Ersatzform (Konjunktiv II)* for **formal** indirect speech if the verb is a "normal" verb if you want

      > Man sagt, ich **tränke** Wasser.
    - Use *"würde-Konjunktiv"* for informal speech. It is also a very good option for formal speech and written texts.

      > Man sagt, ich **würde** Wasser **trinken.**
  - unrealistic wishes, options etc.
    In case of unrealistic wishes, options etc. "würde-Konjunktiv" is the best choice for "normal" verbs in all settings.

    - Use *"würde-Konjunktiv"* for unrealistic wishes, options etc. if the verb is a "normal" verb

      > Ich **würde** gerne Wasser **trinken,** aber hier gibt es keines.